# Where is "on shares" data found in Facebook's api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Clicking a post in Facebook's post insights shows a summary like this:

[image]

I am however bamboozled as to how a post can have 8 likes, 3 comments and 2 shares on shares of this post, without that post having been shared ('0 on post').

Trying to gain further insight into this:

`/{post-id}/insights` doesn't return any share information.

`/{post-id}/sharedposts` returns an empty set, even for posts that have been directly shared.

`/{page-id}/posts` just indicates the "shares on posts" (not on shares) and even omits that if it's zero like in this case.

Where can I find the "On Shares" figures in the api?

Comment: IMHO this is not possible via the Graph API nor FQL...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "on shares" is from people who liked the post because their friend liked it.  and the original person hasn't liked the page.  because the same issue happened with my account 2 Point Perspective and it didn't receive any "shares"!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can conclude, "on shares" numbers can be calculated by total minus "on post" numbers. You can get total numbers from

```
/{page_id}_{post_id}/insights/post_stories_by_action_type
```

and "on post" numbers from

```
/{page_id}_{post_id}/?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares
```

You should be able to get these numbers from /{page_id}_{post_id}/sharedposts/..., but as of [this bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404733043148335/), you won't be able to do so actually.

Also watch out for permissions and Graph API version number.

Answer (score 0):

Had to think this through for awhile, but I finally got it (I think).

What it's basically saying is the following.

First line: you received a total of 8 Likes. The 8 Likes didn't come from your direct post. It came from the shares of other users (however many shares that was).

Second line: same situation as above. Except this time, you had 1 comment on your direct post, while 3 comments came from shares.

Third line: you get the gist.

Here is the exact language that describes how this works from Facebook.

"The metrics you see on a Page post when viewed from your Page's Timeline or in News Feed include likes, comments and shares that happened on the original post. The metrics in your Page Insights include likes, comments and shares from the original post plus any activity that happened if your post was shared. For example, if someone shares your post, and then their friend shares that post, this will be counted as 2 shares in Page Insights."

Source: https://www.facebook.com/help/336143376466063/